# replacing the values in a numpy array with the values of another array against value of one array as index in another

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change the values in a numpy **array(x)** corresponding to the value in numpy **array(y)** at `index = x[index]`

A numpy array `x = [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3]`
another Numpy Array `y = [3,4,0,1,2]`

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = y[x[i]]
```

Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
x = y[x]
```

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array( [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3] )
>>> y = np.array( [3,4,0,1,2] )
>>> y[x]
array([4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1])
```

Or, to demonstrate assignment:

```
>>> x = y[x]
>>> x
array([4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1])
```